# how to connect android to web service and display database on android?

Tags: web-services, eclipse

I am a student and new in android.
I've created a database in server, which is on http://000webhost.com/
now i need to connect the database to my android (eclipse) and display the data.

My question is, how to connect them? 
is there something to do with HTTPClient? if yes, I don't really get the full/correct code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Ksoap2 to connect and fetch data from webserver.. use HTTP for transport. here is link to get started with.. 
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html